# How to resolve MySQL lock timeout error?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timeout, rowlocking

I am getting below listed error many times in my application log.

```
2015-05-19 10:27:57,842 ERROR [Timer-3] [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transactionCouldn't retrieve InnoDB stat
us due to underlying exception:

BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException
MESSAGE: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
```

I know this error can be happen when one thread has locked particular row of table, and second thread is waiting for it and this waiting time exceed certain amount of time.

But how can I optimize MySQL Configuration or my code to overcome this situation?

I have already read [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/#comment-10807521) about isolation level, and I have already set isolation level to `READ COMMITTED`.

Is there any expert advice/solution rather than I have mentioned?